# non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context - why here?

Tags: java, static, compiler-errors

I have a code:

```
package why;

public class Foo
{
    public class Foo1
    {
        String bar;

        public Foo1(String bar)
        {
            this.bar = bar;
        }

        public static Foo1 MYCONSTANT = new Foo(null);
    }

}
```

Why do I get 'non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context'?
I allocate the instance of non-static class.

Why even here?

```
public static Foo getMYCONSTANT()
{
    return new Foo(null, null);
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Can you post the full code? Your snippets really don't help to explain your errors.

Comment: apologies, the previous revision of my question did not contain enough code. Now it does.

Answer (score 6):

Lets take a look at this example:

```
public class MainClass {

  public class NonStaticClass {

    public static NonStaticClass nonStatic = new NonStaticClass();
    //Compile error: The field nonStatic cannot be declared static; 
    //static fields can only be declared in static or top level types
    public static int i = 10;//this field also causes the same compile error
  }

}
```

The problem is that `NonStaticClass` is, well, **not static**. A non static inner class can't contain static fields.

If you want to have a static field in the inner class you need to make the class static.

From the java documentation:

> **Inner Classes**
>
> As with instance methods and variables, an inner class is associated
>   with an instance of its enclosing class and has direct access to that
>   object's methods and fields. Also, **because an inner class is
>   associated with an instance, it cannot define any static members
>   itself**.

For more information take a look at [Nested Classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what your real question is ... but perhaps this might help:

> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern
>
> In the second edition of his book "Effective Java" Joshua Bloch claims
>   that "a single-element enum type is the best way to implement a
>   singleton"[9] for any Java that supports enums. The use of an enum is
>   very easy to implement and has no drawbacks regarding serializable
>   objects, which have to be circumvented in the other ways.

```
public enum Singleton {
        INSTANCE;
}
```